# DualShock 4 controller audio I/O over Bluetooth

Tags: usb, sound, bluetooth, gamepad, bluez

It works by default if you plug in USB, showing two new output devices, S/PDIF and analog. Selecting analog allows you to hear through the 3.5 jack. There's also an input, it works too.
However, when you connect by bluetooth, it shows up as type: gamepad, and the audio devices don't appear.

This is USB:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 054c:09cc Sony Corp. 

|__ Port 11: Dev 13, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
|__ Port 11: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
|__ Port 11: Dev 13, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
|__ Port 11: Dev 13, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
```

Furthermore, the audio devices show up but **don't** work if the controller is connected by both USB and Bluetooth. This may be a good sign?

I tried to use `bluez-tools` but `bt-device -s` gives me

> Failed to start SDP discovery. Please make sure you have bluez-utils installed on your system.

Idk how to fix that, installing bluez from source doesn't seem to do the trick. Please tell me the idiomatic modern way to view bluetooth "capabilites", I am a BT noob.

I also tried the controller with my OnePlus 3T android 8.0.0 Phone, where:

- **In wired mode:** sound is forcefully redirected from "Phone speaker" output to the controller.
- **In bluetooth mode:** it realized that it has audio capabilities, but immediately failed any attempt to pick that as audio output (the
  audio wasn't even interrupted)

(In both cases it also only recognized it as a controller, with quite weird mapping, and not a mouse, so that's pretty tragic.)